# Make models belong to users in django

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am using django.contrib.auth and I am wondering how I can make an instance of a model "belong to" a particular user. Do I need to define a foreign key in the model that points to the user? I want users to keep their CRUD to themselves.

```
# The objects created from this model should belong 
# to the user who created them and should not be 
# viewable by other users of the website.

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Classroom(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __unicode__ (self):
        return self.name
```

Thanks.

Comment: A _model_ or a _instance of the model_? Models are equivalent to tables and instances of models are equivalent to rows. Please clarify what you are asking.

Comment: "objects created from this model" => instances, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to have multiple objects belong to the user, a [foreign key field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) to the User object will work. Note, you can still use a foreign key, and have one instance by passing 
the `unique` attribute to the field definition.

---

If one object (and only one) and belong to a user, use a [one to one field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#ref-onetoone). A one to one field can be accessed from either side of the models

You can use `user.classroom` or `classroom.user`, these bindings can be changed with the `related_name` attribute of one to one field definitions.

Comment: So, looking up objects that belong to the user in the view is enough to prevent users seeing the wrong objects?

Comment: @broinjc No, you need to handle that yourself.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid how would I handle this then?

Comment: @broinjc Handle that in the view with something like `if classroom.user == request.user:...`

Comment: And in a classroom creation form, I would hide the User foreignkey field and automatically fill it in with the current User?

Comment: Yes, but just to clarify, don't hide it. When making the form exclude it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use an

Comment: @JacobValenta `exclude = ['User']` got it. How do I use `classroom.user` in my view? Currently testing with hard coded value `classrooms = Classroom.objcets.filter(User = 2)`

Comment: @broinjc `request.user.classroom_set()` will return all classrooms belonging to that user.

Comment: @JacobValenta it's throwing a "'RelatedManager' object is not callable"

Comment: @broinjc whoops! `request.user.classroom_set().all()`

Comment: @JacobValenta request.user.classroom_set.all() is not returning classes and is not returning an error... hmm

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47812/discussion-between-jacob-valenta-and-broinjc)

Answer (score 3):

This is the general approach I take:

**Creating models that belong to the user**

1. On the model, have a foreign key to the user.
2. Define a custom ModelForm that requires a user to be passed to the constructor (`__init__()`).  Also, override the form's `save()` method so that the user passed to the constructor is added to the model instance, before it's saved.
3. Define class based views based on [`CreateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView) etc. that override the `get_form_kwargs` method to pass the form the user stored in the request.

Here's the code:

```
# models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class MyModel(models.Model):
    "A model that belongs to a user."

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

# forms.py

from django import forms
from .models import MyModel

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for creating/updating MyModels that accepts
    the user as a kwarg.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.instance.user = self.user
        return super(MyModelForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        # Don't show the user on the form
        exclude = ('user',)

# views.py

from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .models import MyModel
from .forms import MyModelForm


class MyModelCreateView(CreateView):
    "View for creating a MyModel belonging to the current user."
    model = MyModel
    form_class = MyModelForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form_kwargs = super(MyModelCreateView,
                        self).get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
        # Pass the current user to the form constructor
        form_kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return form_kwargs
```

**Listing models that belong to the user**

This is more straightforward - you extend `ListView` and filter the queryset by the current user.  ([Read more about `ListView`.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview))

**Editing models that belong to the user**

Use a similar approach to `MyModelCreateView`, but extending an [`UpdateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView) instead.  The important thing here is to check that the user has permission to edit:

```
# views.py
from django.views.generic import UpdateView
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
...

class MyModelUpdateView(UpdateView):
    "View for the current user editing a MyModel."""

    model = MyModel
    form_class = MyModelForm

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        object = super(MyModelUpdateView, self).get_object(*args, **kwargs)
        # Raise a permission denied if the current user doesn't
        # 'own' the MyModel they're trying to edit.
        if object.user != self.request.user:
             raise PermissionDenied

    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form_kwargs = super(MyModelCreateView,
                    self).get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
        # Pass the current user to the form constructor
        form_kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return form_kwargs
```